# One Filter w/ 2 Conditions or 2 Filters?

Tags: java, java-8, filtering, java-stream

I was recently going back through old code changing my foreach loops to streams, and I ran across an if statement like `condition && condition`. So at first I did

```
.stream()
.filter(x -> cond && cond)
```

But then I realised it would look better with two filters, one for each condition.

Which is better convention, and which is more efficient when compiled (if there is any difference at all)?

Comment: If you think it looks better, that's probably the most important thing. Don't underestimate code readability. Any gains here are likely to be minimal, but you could always test it yourself to see.

Comment: Just a guess, but I would imagine that the && version is a little quicker because it only needs to traverse the stream once. I don't have a problem reading this one, either.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll just stick with two filter, since realistically I'm the only one who'll be reading it.

Comment: @TrentSmall whether there is one, two or 30 filters, the stream is only traversed once.

Comment: @JB Nizet Huh, that's pretty cool! I'll have to try those out.

Comment: Do what is most readable.  The performance considerations are generally far less important than readability, and the incremental cost of an added pipeline stage is usually tiny anyway.